# count of internal tables in a tabular image using python

Tags: python

I have been given an image ( a table which is in rectangular shape) and it is again divided into some internal tables. The question is to get the count of those internal tables using python. Could anyone suggest me how to proceed?  Check the below sample image

example_image

[image]

I need to get count = 78 tables

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the image to binary, and compute sum of pixel intensities over image rows, and count peaks in it, then compute the sum of pixel intensities over image columns, and count peaks in it. Those would be the number of horizontal and vertical lines found in the image. Then *N = (num_of_horizontal_lines - 1) * (num_of_vertical_lines - 1)*.

Example code (using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) and [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io)):

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import numpy as np
>>> im = np.array(Image.open('cJyt5.png').convert('L'))
>>> threshold = np.histogram(im, 2)[1][1]
>>> im2 = im < threshold
>>> vert_lines = sum(np.mean(im2, axis=0) > 0.5)
>>> horiz_lines = sum(np.mean(im2, axis=1) > 0.5)
>>> (vert_lines - 1) * (horiz_lines - 1)
78
```

If the lines are more than 1 pixel thick, you need to slightly change the code to not take into account multiple consecutive `True` values in `np.mean(...) > 0.5`.

A simple trick would be to do `sum(np.max(0, np.diff(np.mean(...) > 0.5)))` to count the number of changes from `False` to `True`. (not tested)

Comment: @RRSS Done. Now please consider upvoting / accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @fferri for that sol.It works on the given image and small scale images But it is not working on the large scale even if few changes are done as suggested by you. (Large scale means the images are taken by camera in real time)

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid but your question was about recognizing tables in your computer generated image with 1pixel thick lines. You can easily work around that limitation, but definitely it won't work with non-straight non-axis-aligned lines. For images from a camera I recommend using opencv, in particular apply hough transform to your input image. Open another question and I will answer there.

Comment: @RRSS remember to include an actual example of the image you want to recognize, i.e. the image from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works for your example image, but I cannot guarantee that it'll work for others, as it is untested and may be fragile.

Explanation:

1. Converts image to binary by setting all non-white values to 0 and all white values to 1.
2. Looks for the first horizontal and vertical line of pixels that contain both 0s and 1s.
3. Counts the "squashed" number of pixels with a value of 0 in that line and subtracts 1.
4. Multiplies the horizontal line value from step 3 by the vertical line value from step 3 to get the number of cells.

Dependencies:

- PIL (`pip install Pillow`)

Execution:

`python main.py ./path/to/grid.png`

---

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import dropwhile, groupby
import sys

from PIL import Image


def convert_to_binary(im):
    # first converts to 8-bit values, then to binary.
    return im.convert('L').point(lambda v: 0 if v < 255 else 1, mode='1')


def first_intersection(pixels2d):
    # if it only has one pixel value it's a border
    return next(dropwhile(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1, pixels2d))


def cells_intersected(pixels1d):
    # count the number of non-consecutive 0s and subtracts 1.
    return Counter([g[0] for g in groupby(pixels1d)])[0] - 1


def transpose(lst):
    return list(map(list, zip(*lst)))


def reshape2d(lst, size):
    return [lst[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(lst), size)]


def main():
    with Image.open(sys.argv[1]) as img:
        bin_data = list(convert_to_binary(img).getdata())
        assert(sorted(Counter(bin_data).values()) == 
               sorted(Counter(img.getdata()).values()))
        bin_lst = reshape2d(bin_data, img.width)
        horizontal = first_intersection(bin_lst)
        vertical = first_intersection(transpose(bin_lst))
        print(cells_intersected(horizontal) * cells_intersected(vertical))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I am getting some error at this point "assert(sorted(Counter(bin_data).values()) == 
               sorted(Counter(img.getdata()).values())" it says " assertion error".

Comment: Is that error occurring with the example image? If you create the counters before the assertion and print out the contents, what do you get? This is what I get: `Counter({1: 95882, 0: 7203})
Counter({(255, 255, 255, 255): 95882, (218, 220, 221, 255): 7203})`